# check if there are any elements from one arraylist in another one and print the same elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to check if the list "wordlist" has some elements from the list "list". If it has , these elements should be printed. Just have some difficulties with syntax to compare 2 lists in java.  Here is my code:

```
File files = new File("E:/test/dictionary.txt");
String[] words = file.split(" ");
List<String> wordlist = Arrays.asList(words);
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(files);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    scanner.close();
    for (String word : wordlist) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
    for (String oleg : list) {
        System.out.println(oleg);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient intersection of two List<String> in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400838/efficient-intersection-of-two-liststring-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am misreading your question because the solution seems pretty simple to me. All you need to do is run a `for-loop` and use the `ArrayList` `contains(Object O)` method or run a nested `for-loop` and use the `String` `equals(String O)` method. See below.

**METHOD 1:**

```
for(int a = 0; a < wordlist.size(); a++)
    if(wordlist.contains(list.get(a)))
        System.out.println(list.get(a));
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
for(int a = 0; a < wordlist.size(); a++)
    for(int b = 0; b < wordlist.size(); b++)
        if(wordlist.get(a).equals(list.get(b));
            System.out.println(list.get(b));
```

In the second example I keep `wordlist.size()` as the factor in both loops because both `list` and `wordlist` should be the same size, or at least I assume that.

Also, with references or variables that more than one word, Java convention dictates that good practice would be to capitalize the first letter of all subsequent words, that is, `wordlist` should be `wordList`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, use [`Collection.retainAll(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) (per the linked Javadoc to retain *only the elements in this collection that are contained in the specified collection*) like

```
wordlist.retainAll(list);
System.out.println(wordlist);
// for (String word : wordlist) {                              
//     System.out.println(word);                                
// }
// for (String oleg : list) {
//     System.out.println(oleg);
// }
```