# Check if String contains part of other string Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have some strings defined in my Java application, like so:

```
 m3 = "T, V, E";
 m2 = "T, W, E";
```

as an example.

Now I need to check, which parts of the strings match. So in this case, I would want a string `m4`, containing `T, E`, as a result.

In that case for example:

```
m1 = "A, S";
m3 = "T, V, E";
```

i would want an empty (but declared) string.

Or is there a better way, to do it with another method then with strings? I'm actually declaring those strings by hand. Would an array be better? If yes, how could I do it with arrays?

Comment: what have you got so far? this is just your assignment

Comment: @Stultuske I tried like using substr() to check, but basically thats not what I want because I need the "single letters" to be checked (seperated by a comma) and not the "string"

Comment: it sounds like you want the intersection of two sets. (there is a collection class for Set)

Comment: by thinking again, it might be better to declare those variables as arrays of characters. But is there then a way to check, which array elements match?

Comment: or @PatrickParker how could I do that?

Comment: Are these strings always delimited by commas? If so, you can easily check it.

Comment: Just convert your strings in Set of char. it will be easier if you have those strings declarated in arrays. Check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400838/efficient-intersection-of-two-liststring-in-java

Comment: @Jay yes, and thats why I thought arrays might make more sence, because I don't need to `split` the strings first, but still I don't know how to check if they contain the same values then

Comment: You can use array if the both strings arrays are same length then you can match value of each index of both string.
if values matches then assign that value to new array.

Comment: @ZaighamRaza every array might have another length (which is between 1 and 3)

Comment: @nameless then don't use array because it will costly due to multiple checks then use java split function to split that words by adding (,- etc) such indicators to each word of your array to split.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 you can proceed as below :

```
    String s1 = "T,V,E";
    String s2 = "T,W,E";

    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList(s1.split(","));
    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList(s2.split(","));

    List<String> result = l1.stream().filter(l2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(String.join(",", result));
```

The result is "T,E" as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in many ways. One of the ways is using **Set**.

First, split **m1** the characters by (comma) and add it to **HashSet**. Then split the **m2** characters and add it to **ArrayList**. Now by the for loop try to add the **ArrayList** characters to **HashSet**. You will get false from the add method (`Set.add()`) if it is not added (because the character is already there). If you get false print the character or add it to another ArrayList.

```
        String m3 = "T, V, E";
        String m2 = "T, W, E";

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(m3.split(",")));
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(m2.split(","));
        for (String s : list) {
            if (!set.add(s)) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
```

Result will be T and E

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate data structure is Set.

```
    Set<String> m3 = new TreeSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(m3, "T", "V", "E");
    Collections.addAll(m3, "T, V, E".split(",\\s*")); // Alternatively.

    Set<String> m2 = new HashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(m2, "T", "W", "E");

    Set<String> m5 = new TreeSet<>(m2);
    m5.retainAll(m3);
```

Java 9:

```
    Set<String> m3 = Set.of("T", "V", "E");
    Set<String> m2 = Set.of("T", "W", "E");
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your `String` follows this pattern : `..., ..., ....` , you could split them and filter only each String that is contained in the two arrays.
You can then collect them into a `List` and join them with `,` :

```
List<String> commonStrings = Arrays.stream(m2.split(",\\s"))
      .flatMap(s-> Arrays.stream(m3.split(",\\s"))
      .filter(s2.equals(s)))          
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

String joinedString = String.join(",", commonStrings);
```

Note that this code doesn't return the exact number of equals occurrences in the two `String`s.
So if one `String` contains two `A` and the other one `A`, you will get two `A` in the result.
If it doesn' matter and you want to get only distinct `String`, you can invoke `distinct()` before `collect()`.

Otherwise, to return the exact number of equals occurrences, during the processing, as soon as a `String` part is consumed (`A` for example) as the two parts are equal in the two `String`s, you could create new `String`s from the actual `String`s but by removing this `String` part .

Answer (score 0):

you can use the split() function as the following

```
String a="A, B, C, D";
        String b="B, C, D";
        String[] a_chars =a.split(", "); //returns array with A B C D
        String[] b_chars =b.split(", "); //returns array with B C D
```

this whay you have 2 arrays of strings now you can compare them using 2 (for) loops

```
String result="";
        for(int c=0;c<a_chars.length;c++)
        {
            for(int d=0;d<b_chars.length;d++)
            {
                if(a_chars[c].equals(b_chars[d]))
                {
                    result+=a_chars[c]+", ";
                }
            }
        }
```

now you have the result string like this `result="B, C, D, "`

check of the length of result is greater than zero 
if so erase the lase 2 characters which are `,`

```
if(result.length()>0)result=result.substring(0,result.length()-2);
```

if the length of the result string is zero that means there is no matching letters so no need to modify it

Answer (score 0):

String s1 = "T,V,E";
    String s2 = "T,W,E";

```
List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList(s1.split(","));
List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList(s2.split(","));

List<String> result = l1.stream().filter(l2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(String.join(",", result));
```

result = T&E
This is good answer I will tell you too this